# The text box have space character

Tags: php, post-meta

I made a text box to input number and after the user click the save button, it will save the value into the `wp_postmeta`.

But, the problem is that, after I refresh the page the number will content with space character.

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
<div class = "meta-td03">
                <input type="text" class="dwwp-row-content03" name="bonus_point" id="bonus_point" value="
                    <?php 
                        if ( ! empty ( $dwwp_stored_meta['bonus_point'] ) ) {
                            echo esc_attr($dwwp_stored_meta['bonus_point'][0] );
                        } 
                    ?>"
               />
            </div>
```

Save function:

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'bonus_point' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'bonus_point', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'bonus_point' ] ) );
    }
```

And I go to the database, and the value actually is `86`.

This problem is came after I changed the editor to `Eclipse` from `netBean`. And I tried to go back `netBean`, but it isn't work. How to fix this problem? 
Thx a lot.

Comment: The problem is new lines inside `value` attribute. Have you tried: `value="<?php if (...) ?>"`.

Comment: Oh YS thx! Problem is fixed. But why this problem appear?

Comment: @Capslock10 the problem is that you hit the `enter` key after your `value="` then you opened your `<?php` tag, so before the `<?php` tag and after your `=` you have a new line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Dan9 said, you have a new line inside your `value` attribute.

you can write your conditional statement this way too

```
<div class = "meta-td03">
  <input type="text" class="dwwp-row-content03" name="bonus_point" id="bonus_point" value="<?php ! empty( $dwwp_stored_meta['bonus_point'] ) ? echo esc_attr($dwwp_stored_meta['bonus_point'][0] ) : ''; ?>" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thx a lot. Is it the attribute should inside one line? As it make the line so long...

Comment: You can break line inside the `<?php ?>` tag but any new line outside of PHP tags will be considered HTML so it will be rendered by the browser.  I don't make new lines when it's not necessary, especially to avoid this kind of issues!

Comment: OK. THX A LOT!!